# Does Visual Studio 2013 update 4 include previous updates 1, 2 and 3?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to update my ms visual studio 2013 ultimate. What is the right way to keep it up to date? Do I need to install update 1, 2, 3 and 4 one by one or only update 4 will make it up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the base release and the update. As per [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994375):

> Visual Studio 2013 updates are cumulative releases.

That's supported by the text further down:

> If you do not have Visual Studio 2013 (original-release version), then run one of the following downloads, both Visual Studio 2013 and Update 4 are installed.

That means update 4 contains everything that was in updates 1, 2 and 3 (unless it was something that was *removed* because it was buggy of course).